# Arranging Sqlite data in tabular form

Tags: android, sqlite, format

I want to arrange my sqlite data in a tabular format. Right now, I am retrieving the data to a textview. But it does not arrange itself under the column name, which looks confusing. I want it to be displayed atleast under the right column name. I have tried adding multiple spaces between the multiple getString() while retrieving the data, but doesnt seem to help.!

Can anyone help??
Thanks already.

heres the code

```
public String getData()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String [] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROW_ID, KEY_KM, KEY_FUEL_QTY, KEY_FUEL_PRICE, KEY_TOTAL_COST, KEY_MILEAGE, KEY_DATE,KEY_TANK_FULL};
        fuelCursor =  ourDatabase.query(FUEL_DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String resultSQL= "";

        while(fuelCursor.moveToNext())
        {
            resultSQL = resultSQL + fuelCursor.getString(0) + "         " + fuelCursor.getString(1) + "         " + fuelCursor.getString(2) +"           "+ fuelCursor.getString(3) + "          " + fuelCursor.getString(4) + "          " + fuelCursor.getString(5) + "         " + fuelCursor.getString(6) + "        " + fuelCursor.getString(7) + "\n ";  
        }
            return resultSQL;
    }
```

DIsplaying the data in textview:-

```
 TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtGetFuelInfo);
StoredInfo info = new StoredInfo(this);
Expense fe2= new Expense();
info.open();
String fuelData= info.getData();
info.close();
tv.setText(fuelData);
```

heres what it looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use a `ListView` and a `custom layout` containing no. of `textviews` equal to your rows and pass their reference to a `cursoradapter` and bind that adapter to your `ListView` .. it should appear in proper manner.
And use proper gravity value for `TextViews`

you can refer following links for adapters and sqlite

[ListView](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/)

[Adapters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)

[SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html)

[Sqlite_ContentProvider_Adapters_Loaders](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/)

**Update :**

u can refer to following example :-
[example](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html)

its almost the same , just arrange your TextViews in horizontal fashion and pass the cursor you are fetching from to the cursor adapter.

```
 fuelCursor =  ourDatabase.query(FUEL_DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: thanks for replying. It will be really helpful if you give me an example

Comment: I have updated my answer , try the example and reply if you still need any help